# Finding the number of occurrences of a string in another string

Tags: c++, optimization, strings

I have written a program, in which I have to find the number of occurrences (overlapping + non-overlapping) of a string in another string.

```
// variable to keep track of word
int i=0;
for(vector<string>::iterator it = p.begin(); it!=p.end(); it++){
    frequency[i]=0;
    int start=0;
    while(true){
        start = s.find(*it, start);

        if(start==-1){  // not found
            break;
        } else{
            frequency[i]++;
            start++;
        }
    }

    i++;
}
```

I am finding the starting index `start` of the match, and then again searching for the string starting from 'start+1' this time, and so on. The length of the string `s`, in which searching has to be performed is 50,00,000. And total number of keywords (stored in vector `p` here) is 500 (each having length of 5000).

Comment: What exactly are you looking to improve? Or are you looking for a general review?

Answer (score 3):

I don't like nested loops.  They are generally unnecessry
and are often confusing. So instead of your two loops, I would extrac the
inner loop to a function, for example:

```
int key_search(const std::string& s, const std::string& key)
{
    int count = 0;
    size_t pos=0;
    while ((pos = s.find(key, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        ++count;
        ++pos;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This searches the inputs string `s` for occurances of string `key` and returns
the number of matches.  A few things are worth noting:

- The parameters are passed as const references - `const` because you don't change them and references for efficiency.
- I used `string::npos` as the idicator of failure from `string`s `find`
  method, instead of -1 (-1 would give a warning from the compiler if you have
  sign conversion warnings enabled).
- I didn't use a `while(true)` loop but instead used the return from `s.find`
  directly to control the loop.
- I pre-incremented variables instead of post-increment (++pos, not pos++)
  which can be more efficient (although with built in types it makes no
  difference).
- `pos` (your `start`) is of type `size_t`, not int. Or you could use `std::string::size_type`, which is the also `size_t`.
- It is normal to prefix your use of standard library things with `std::`, so
  `string` becomes `std::string` etc.

The main loop now just needs to call `key_search`

```
int i = 0;
for (auto it = keys.begin(); it != keys.end(); ++it){
    frequency[i] = key_search(s, *it);
    ++i;
}
```

With C++11 you can use `auto` to simplify the iterator definition.  You don't
show what `frequency` is, but I'm assuming it is an array (which are generally
best avoided in C++).